# Error CS2001: Source file '.cs' could not be found

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error on a project of mine when I try to build... Error CS2001: Source file '.cs' could not be found. I took the two files that are causing this error out on purpose because they conflict with other files and cannot be in there. How can I resolve this error without putting the 2 files back in the solution?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "they conflict with other files"? How did you remove the files? (Did you just delete them in Explorer, or in VS?) Does the actual error message list the specific files?

Comment: Clean your solution then rebuild it. Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: For others, ensure that the offending file is actually added to source control in Visual Studio. I had this error, and the file was physically there, but the little lock icon was not displaying. I right-clicked and added to source control, and the error went away.

Comment: In my case, relative file path length was the issue. Not sure if it is an OS constrain or VS constrain.

Comment: Also check the case of the file on your drive, in project file and in the error message. Never forget Git is case sensitive and Windows is not. Most of my issues come from wrong case.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

They are likely still referenced by the project file. Make sure they are deleted using the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio - it should show them as being missing (with an exclamation mark).

Comment: This happened to me when renaming a .cs file.  It wouldn't show the "missing" file until I closed Visual Studio and reopened project.  Removed the invalid reference and had to add the renamed file back to the project.

Comment: I found this similar issue, but putting the missing file again, this worked.

Comment: Show all files helps in Visual Studio.

Comment: Character Casing was the culprit in my case, when attempting to build a Windows-developed project on a Linux server. At some point I changed the casing of a file using the Windows machine, and GitHub kept the old casing, which did not exist on a case-sensitive file system like Linux.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Rogers, I spent like an hr to fix this. In my case some temp files were added to the solution (they had to be deleted)

Answer (score 26):

I open the project,.csproj, using a notepad and delete that missing file reference.

Comment: this fixed it for me too, restarting VS and clean/rebuild both didn't fix it

Comment: if none works,then just try closing visual studio and reopen... it worked for me

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem, too.

Possible causes in my case: I had deleted a duplicated view twice and a view model. 
I reverted one of the deletes and then the InitializeComponent error appeared. 
I took these steps.

1. I checked all of the solutions mentioned on this question. The class
   name and build action were correct.
2. I Cleaned my Solution and rebuilt. Another error appeared. "Error CS2001: Source file '.cs' could not be found"
3. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406924/error-cs2001-source-file-cs-could-not-be-found) and followed the steps.
4. I reloaded the project and cleaned/rebuilt again.
5. My solution builds without errors and my application works now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I add file as Link from another project and then rename file in source project that cause problem in destination project. I delete linked file in destination and add again with new name.