# CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: .net-core, resharper

My api build fails with the following error, even though I have disabled Resharper.

```
 Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 
'MyApi.Common.Models.Enums.ProductionWorkflowStatus 
 [C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Shared\vAny
 \DecompilerCache\decompiler\somelongnumber\bd\some 
 numberbc\ProductionWorkflowStatus.cs(9)]' to 
 'MyApi.Common.Models.Enums.ProductionWorkflowStatus 
 [C:\Users\kirst\.nuget\packages\MyApi.common\1.0.124\lib
 \netstandard2.0\MyApi.Common.dll]'. 
 An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    
 ApiForApi3  
 D:\dev\ApiForApi3\ApiForApi3\Feature_Job_Management\JobDataRead.cs 
 544    Active
```

[Update]

I deleted the relevant file in

```
C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Shared\vAny
 \DecompilerCache\decompiler
```

And then I was able to build.

However the problem has returned.

I can see the following in the .csproj file  ( edited)

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="C:\Users\kirst\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Shared\vAny\DecompilerCache\decompiler\long number\bd\long number\ProductionWorkflowStatus.cs" Link="ProductionWorkflowStatus.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962066/cs0436-type-conflicts-with-the-imported-type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406924/error-cs2001-source-file-cs-could-not-be-found

Comment: Am i reading that right, the you have some reference to namespace X in some nuget in your projects, and then JetBrains Resharper is decompiling it and also adding another reference to the project so you're ending up with duplicate code?

Comment: How did it happen? Did you decompile it for some reason of needing to change th code in it, or internal inspection maybe? Did you (accidentally) reference the decompiled version? What happns if you remove all refernces to it from the solution's projects, and then re-add references by the nuget package manager?

Comment: I did right click ProductionWorkflowStatus and go to the definition thus showing the decompiled code.... could that have caused the problem somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the ItemGroup from the .csproj file and the problem was solved.

Comment: but later the issue returns